# Algebra with whole no. 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$1 -  ( x + 1 / 2 ) + ( X - 2 / 6) $

My working

$ 1 - ( 6x + 6 + 2x - 4 / 12 ) 
= 12/12 - 8x+2 / 12 
= -8x+10 / 12
= -4x + 5 / 6 $

Why is my working wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where has the $X$ disappeared to?

Comment: Do you mean $1-\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{x-2}6$? In that case, $(x+1)/2$ is the correct way of writing, and $(x+1/2)$ is wrong.